# JavaScript For Loop, Specific Values Needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need a double for loop to produce a certain series of values. This is part of finding the neighbor cells for a maze generation program I am trying to make (using the DFS method). Here is some pseudo-code:

```
var values = [];
for (...) {
    for (...) {
        values.push([i, j]);
    }
}
```

After the loops have run, "values" should be `[[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]]`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: JavaScript don't really have 2-D arrays; are you after array containing arrays as its own items?

Comment: It's really not clear what exactly you intend to do. Which are the values you want to loop over?

Comment: Yes, I use them all of the time.

Comment: I need the loops to create an array of arrays which has the value [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]].

Comment: @ShadowWizard an array of arrays is a 2d-structure, isn't it? However that does not change the fact, that this question is far to vague to provide a good answer.

Comment: why does it have to be loops? school assignment says so?

Comment: @ConnerRuhl Why do you need to use loops instead of just `var values =  [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]];`?

Comment: No, I am making a maze game, and I want to check the neighbor cells if the are already occupied or not. This is part of the DFS maze method.

Comment: @Conner why not just write `var values = [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]];` then?

Comment: I could do that, but I am trying to tackle this logically. I probably won't implement it, I just want to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well. your exact result could be achieved like this:

```
var seed_values = [1, -1, 0, 0];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    values.push([seed_values[i], seed_values[(i+2)%4]]);
}
```

Comment: Even though this isn't exactly what I was looking for, I think it will most help others who need to do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
        if (Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) == 1)
        values.push([i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for, but is there any way you can think of that only runs four times? I am fairly sure that code would run six times.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

There is no real structure in your array, so loops would only overcomplicate it. Use the array literal you already have.

If it were `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]`, this could help you:

```
for (var values=[], i=0; i<Math.PI*2; i+=Math.PI/2)
    values.push([Math.cos(i), Math.sin(i)]);
```

…but unfortunately does not compute exact zeros, only something very close - you also had to `Math.round`.

For your array and the nested loop structure, I can only think of

```
var values = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (var j=1; j>=-1; j-=2, i*=-1) {
        values.push([i, +!i && j]);
    }
}
```

Ugly, isn't it? But it does run two nested loops, each of them two times :-)

Comment: That is a very interesting use of trigonometry. Very cool.

Comment: [That's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) what I though initially when I saw your array at first, but yours is in a different order.